# n tasks assigned to n computers, what is the EX value of a computer getting 5 or more tasks?

Tags: probability, expectation

Say a central server assigns each of n tasks uniformly and independently at random to n computers connected to it on a network. Say a computer is ‘overloaded’ if it receives 5 or more tasks.

Q: Calculate the expected number of overloaded computers.

I thought of doing [1 - Pr(a computer is not overloaded)] but that leads me to a complicated expression of:
$$1 - PR(NotOver) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^4  \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{i} { \left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)}^{n-i}$$
multiplying this by n would(hopefully) give the Expected value. But the answer seems not very elegant atall, is there something I'm missing or an easier way to tackle this?
Thanks!

Comment: For $n\gg 0$, consider the Poisson distribution

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I think that should be $n\gg1$?

Comment: "hopefully" can be left out. The idea Exp$=n\times$ Pr(overloaded) is correct.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Then I multiply by n for the expected? If so I got ~ 0.368*n for the expected, does that seem about right?

Comment: Looking at large $n$ I get $0.00366n$ as a likely upper bound

Comment: @Henry That seems way too large. Are we sure the expression for P(overloaded) given in the question is correct?

Comment: @Imran - missed a zero or two  (now edited) - thank you

Comment: Okay, I made an error in my calculation. I got a value of ~0.00366n using Poisson correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hagen von Eitzen suggestion of using the Poisson distribution in fact provides an upper bound.

For large $n$, with an expected number of tasks per computer of  $\frac{n}{n} = 1$, the probability that a single computer *is not* overloaded is about $e^{-1}\left(1 + \frac{1}{1!}+ \frac{1}{2!}+ \frac{1}{3!}+ \frac{1}{4!}\right) \approx 0.99634015317$ and so the probability a single computer *is* overloaded is about $0.00365984683$.

For smaller $n$, the probability a single computer is overloaded is less than this, because high numbers of tasks (many more than the expectation) going to a single computer is less likely with smaller $n$.

So $0.00365984683$ is an upper bound on a single computer being overloaded, and by linearity of expectation $0.00365984683n$ is an upper bound on the expected number of computers being overloaded.

For what it is worth, the probabilities a single computer is overloaded  for different $n$ are

```
n      probability 
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0.00032
6      0.0006644376
7      0.0009701983
8      0.0012300611
9      0.0014492806
10     0.0016349374
20     0.0025739403
30     0.0029210503
40     0.0031003767
50     0.0032097420
100    0.0034323216
1000   0.0036368780
10000  0.0036575478
100000 0.0036596171
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your formula for the `P(overloaded)` is wrong. It looks like you are trying to calculate

`1 - (P(0 tasks) + P(1 task) + ... + P(4 tasks))`

However the probability of k tasks is ${n \choose k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{(n-k)}$, not simply $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{(n-k)}$. You are missing the binomial coefficient.

So the exact formula for `E[overloaded]` is:

$n\left(1-\sum_{i=0}^4 {n \choose i}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^i\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{(n-i)}\right)$

To answer your question, I don't believe there are any tricks to simplify this any further.

Consider using the [Multiplicative Chernoff Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_.28relative_error.29) to estimate an upper bound on the probability of one computer being overloaded and then multiplying by $n$ to get an upper bound on the expected number of overloaded computers.

Let $X_i$ be a random variable describing the number of tasks assigned to computer $i$. We have $E(X_i) = 1$, and the Chernoff bound of the probability of $X_i$ being overloaded is given by:

$$P(X_i > 4) = P \Big( X_i > (1+3) \cdot 1 \Big) < \frac {\textrm e^3} {(1+3)^{1+3}}$$

and so the expected number of overloaded computers can by bounded by:

$$E \left( \sum X_i \right) = \sum E(X_i) < n \frac {\textrm e^3} {(1+3)^{1+3}} \sim 0.078 n .$$

This seems to be a loose bound, however. For example simulating in Python for `n=1000000` gives `0.0037*n`:

```
>>> n = 1000000; t = [randint(1,n) for i in range(n)]; c = Counter(t); sum(1 for v in c.values() if v > 4)/n    
0.003653
```

Comment: But is this just a value for the upper bound?

Comment: Yes it is, unfortunately. I ran some simulations and the bound seems fairly loose in this case.